# Avoid reporting warnings/errors for rule change until file is edited for another reason?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I've just made a load of updates to a project and changed the TypeScript, ESLint rules etc. One thing I did was introduce the no semi-colon rule.

Now there are warnings/errors about every single semi colon still in the project (obviously this is what I wanted). There are also errors related to the TypeScript config changes I made. But I don't want to fix them all in 1 PR as that will be massive.

Is it possible to ignore these issues unless you open / edit the file somehow or what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: *"One thing I did was introduce the no semi-colon rule."* Well, obviously, that was your big mistake. **;-D**

Comment: the update I've done seems to have raised errors in TS that were not there beforehand.would be good to ignore these if possible

Comment: Okay, so not just the semicolons, but other errors as well. I think the edit works for that. :-)

Comment: yes that's right, my bad. just wanted to touch all bases. I've managed to set settings in .env that disables warnings for eslint, now just TS

Comment: But doing that in `.env` is going to prevent the warnings on files you change afterward as well, isn't it?

Comment: yeh, possibly. it was the only half reasonable thing I found so far. not sure there is a good solution

Comment: also @T.J.Crowder is it necessary to check lint in CI if you have a pre-commit hook?

Comment: I think that's probably a matter of opinion. For me, it's overkill if you've already done it at an earlier stage (like pre-commit), but I haven't worked in really, really big teams; largest I've worked on was about 20.